# Is Serial Connectivity reliable in Router Communication?

Tags: cisco

Is Serial Connectivity reliable in Router Communication? 
If Serial Cable gives loses during Communication, how we resolve this problem?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

A very wide range of communications technologies are serial, from RS-232, I<sup>2</sup>C, ethernet and many, many, others.

As a matter of physics, if you put a signal into something it will come out slightly different.  As a matter of engineering therefore, instead of saying mechanism X has or doesn't have errors, it's normal to regard all communications channels as having some underlying noise, interference or other problems which cause errors, and speak of how much there is.  The [bit error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_error_rate) article at Wikipedia has a good introduction.

And instead of thinking about what's desirable ("no errors"), we think about what's acceptable ("few errors").  Depending how we define "few", We then make engineering tradeoffs between complexity, money, speed, reliability,

The main techniques for reducing errors are:

- Separate your signals from sources of interference (eg physical distance)
- Remove sources of noise from the system (eg better circuit design)
- Use inherently better materials (eg fatter cables, matched-length cables, thinner fibres)
- Use methods to insulate signals from interference (eg separate data and power cables)
- Use most appropriate signalling method (current vs voltage vs differential over cable, modulations, FM vs AM, optical)
- Use shorter wires, perhaps with repeaters (eg re-create signal before too degraded)
- Use different clocking (asynchronous, synchronous)
- Use different biasing (eg [NRTZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-return-to-zero), [manchester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code), [4b5b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4B5B))
- Use slower bitrate (eg 100baseT vs 10000baseT)
- Use error detecting codes (eg [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit), [checksums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum), [Verhoef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verhoeff_algorithm))
- Use error correcting codes (eg [Hamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code), [Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code))
- Use retransmission (eg TCP)
- Use multiple links and dynamic routing (eg OSPF)
- Use multiple transmission and voting (eg NTP)

Certain materials degrade over time (cable insulation for example, and many kinds of capacitor) which change the noise and other properties of a signalling system, so indeed (as given in another answer) replacing degraded cables will often help.

In general a communication technology is as reliable its their engineering allows.  Most RS-232 links, for example, have no error-detection or correction; while all ethernet systems have at least the Frame Check Sequence to reject frames with errors, collisions etc.  But many industrial control systems use asynchronous, at slow speeds, over RS-485, with checksums and constant transmission, in order to maximise reliability-per-unit-money in what are often very electrically noisy environments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes serial communication are reliable, as long as the cables meet the specifications, are not damaged and don't suffer too much interference from external sources.

The same is true for other cable types however, like UTP.

If a cable gives loses, well it doesn't meet anymore the specs, so it has to be changed.